# Riemann invariants of a special hyperbolic system

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

How can one compute the Riemann invariants of the following one dimensional hyperbolic system?
$$\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}_t + \begin{pmatrix} -v & -u \\
|v|-k & \mathrm{sgn}(v)u
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}_x = 0, \ $$
where $k \in \mathbb R$. I am stuck because the eigenvectors of the system $F =(f_1, f_2)$ and $G=(g_1,g_2)$ have both components which depend on both $u$ and $v$, so I cannot get the Riemann invariants $r_1,r_2$ from $\nabla r_1 = (-f_2,f_1)$ and $\nabla r_2 = (-g_2,g_1)$

Comment: It doesn't matter that the matrix is dependent on $u, v$, see the examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_invariant#Example) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513008/finding-the-riemann-invariants-of-a-system-of-2-pdes?rq=1).

Comment: @mattos In both examples you point out, the *eigenvector* has components that are either constant or depend only on one of the variables each. So this doesn't cover my example

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question because you have written 'I am stuck because the eigen**value** of the system...' and so I thought this was a question about the dependence of the eigenvalues on $u, v$, though it has now become clear to me from the text after the above quote that you actually meant eigen**vector**. I'll try and take a look at the question in the morning if I remember.