# Are Riemann invariants & eigenspaces uniquely defined?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

I am trying to understand some derivations surrounding the Riemann Invariants for the system:
$$  
\begin{pmatrix} 
u_t \\
\eta_t 
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix} 
u & 1 \\
\eta & u
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
u_x \\
\eta_x 
\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

So far, all I have self-derived is that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2}=u\pm \sqrt{\eta}$
with corresponding eigenvectors:$  
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
\pm \sqrt{\eta}
\end{pmatrix}$

I know that the Riemann invariants are $R_{1,2}(\eta,u)=u\pm 2\sqrt{\eta}$ and I noticed I can arrive at the same invariants from [another stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2513008) which stated: "The corresponding Riemann invariants $R_\mp$ have their gradient orthogonal to the eigenvectors". Using this info I found that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
\pm \sqrt{\eta}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\nabla_{\bf U} R_\mp = 0 ,\qquad\text{e.g.}\qquad
\nabla_{\bf U} R_\mp = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ \mp \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\eta}}\end{pmatrix} .
$$

Where ${\bf U} = (u,\eta)^\top$. Which, when I solved via integration (excluding the arbitrary constant), gave me the correct Riemann invariants above. However, eigenvectors are determined up to a multiplicative constant. This is also true for the orthogonal vector, and if I replace $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ \mp \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\eta}}\end{pmatrix}$ with the equally orthogonal $\begin{pmatrix} \eta\\ \mp \sqrt{\eta}\end{pmatrix}$ (or the various other products I can make), I get entirely different values for the invariant via integration!

Am I doing this correctly? If so, how do I justify the issue I demonstrated? I feel pretty lost here, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riemann invariants are not unique. They are functions of $(u,\eta)$ that are constant on characteristics, but if $R$ is constant on a curve then so is $2+R^2$, or any function of $R$.

Where you wrote "e.g." is a mistake because your example is not a gradient, by the mixed partial derivative test. It needs a multiple of that, an integrating factor.